# Diffie-Hellman Implementation

Tags: python-3.x, diffie-hellman

Making my own Diffie-Hellman "Implementation" so I can understand it better. Is my implementation correct? Whenever I run it ga takes FOREVER. Using RFC 3526 2048-bit for my prime and generator.

```
from os import path, getcwd
from secrets import randbelow

__location__ = path.realpath(
    path.join(getcwd(), path.dirname(__file__)))

# RFC 3526 2048-bit
f = open(__location__ + "\\prime.txt", "r")
p = int(f.read(),16)
g = 2
print(p)

a = randbelow(p-1)+1
b = randbelow(p-1)+1

ga = (g**a)%p
gb = (g**b)%p

gab1 = (ga**b)%p
gab2 = (gb**a)
```